# How do I mount a Windows partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I installed Ubuntu on a laptop through the windows installer. It is very different in that there is not a way to manually partition the HDD. After completing the install, fdisk -l shows:

```
/dev/sda1    Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2    HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3    HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4    Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

Unfortunately, none of them seem to be the Windows partition that I'm looking for. These happen to be recovery partitions. Anyone have any ideas on how to mount or find the Windows 7 partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu installer **Wubi** does not create a partition for Ubuntu, but rather creates a file inside of the Windows partition to contain Ubuntu. Therefore, when running Ubuntu installed with Wubi, its own "partition" is simply a file inside of your Windows partition.

Your Windows partition is mounted in Ubuntu under **/host**, since you installed with Wubi.